# To construct jump discontinuous function

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, continuity, piecewise-continuity

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{\tan kx}{x}, & x<0\\
3x + 2k^2, &x\ge 0
\end{cases}
$$

Hi! I'm trying to construct a function  from this problem with jump discontinuity but from my knowledge the variable $x$ in the denominator with limit approaching $0$ for the left side of it would would result $x=0$ making it discontinuous with a vertical asymptote hence *infinite discontinuity*?
How can I compute a value for $k$ to keep it as discontinuous with a **jump**?

Comment: Hint: $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan kx}{x} = k$

Comment: I didn't quite understand your question, are you asking for values of $k$ such that it has a jump discontinuity? There are infinite $k$'s that would fit.

Comment: Perhaps you are constructing a function *without* a jump discontinuity?

Comment: It seems the [original question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3983185/jump-discontinuity-of-function?) asked for three examples of such functions with jump discontinuities.

Comment: @logichtech yes that's the requirement. I'm unsure of any systematic method instead of just substituting random values.

Comment: It seems simplest to figure out which $k$'s eliminate the jump discontinuity, and then pick three $k$'s which don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^-} \frac{ \tan(kx)}{x} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^-} \frac{ \frac{k\sin(kx)}{\cos(kx)}}{kx} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^-} \frac{ \sin(kx)}{kx} \cdot \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^-}\frac{k}{\cos(kx)} = k$$

[Using the known $\frac{\sin(kx)}{kx}$ limit](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/1.-differentiation/part-a-definition-and-basic-rules/session-8-limits-of-sine-and-cosine/MIT18_01SCF10_Ses8a.pdf)

Thus we need to check for what values of $k$ we have a continuity, or in other words the two functions have the same output at $x=0$:

$$ k = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} 3x + 2k^2 = 2k^2 \\ k = 2k^2 \\ k = 0, \frac{1}{2}$$

Thus, if you want a function with a jump continuity you need to pick some values that are not $0.5, 0$

Comment: For other proofs of the known sin(x)/x->1 limit, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/75130/137524